# Change Form Styling When It's Focused

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

I have a comment form and I set the `opacity` for that form to `0.7`

Now I want to change the `opacity` to `1` only when the users are filling out that form. How can I do that?

I tried using `:focus` selector on the form id but it doesn't seem to work at all.

```
#comment_form
{
    opacity: 0.7;
}

#comment_form:focus
{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Or perhaps there are other ways to achieve this that would be a better solution? (Like maybe using Javascript?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to change the opacity of the *form* when an *input* inside that form is focused.

You can't select elements in CSS based on what descendants they have, so this requires JavaScript.

For example, an (untested) YUI 3 approach would be:

```
var form = Y.one('#comment_form');
form.delegate('focus', function (e) { 
    form.addClass('focused');
}, 'input');
```

And then:

```
#comment_form.focused
{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

You would need similar code for the blur event, and I would recommend adding a class to make it translucent using JS so that it is always fully opaque if JS is not available.

Answer (score 1):

[:focus does not work so well in IE 5-8](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html).

Anyway, the :focus pseudo class should be on the individual input elements, like `textarea`, `input` and so on, not the whole form.

Edit: For a rudimentary solution to this, see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nswtk/).

Comment: If I do that, that means, each individual items inside the form will have it's opacity change only when that specific item is on `focus`. I want the whole form that means everything inside of it to have the `opacity` changed.

Comment: Oh, sorry. The form element does not support the focus event, so you'll have to write a JS solution, afaik. Do you use jquery?